# mail app changing the automatic text in replies and forwarded emails

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

When you reply to an email (in the Apple Mail app on osx), the original email text is prepended by a line:
"On Jun 20, 2022, at 9:36 AM, ... wrote:"

How can I change this text? More specifically can it be changed based on the account I am replying from? I work in a multi-language environment and I use different accounts to communicate with people with different languages. I prefer americans have their weird way of date formatting, others have the text in their own language with different date/time formatting.

Comment: That's based on the client you use, it's not endemic to the idea of email.

Comment: @MarcWilson Sorry, unfortunate formulation, I updated the question. I am referring to the "Mail" app of the OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Mail uses the date display preferences within macOS. Try changing the date format in the Language & Region preference pane --> Advanced... --> Dates tab and change it to a more universal format.

[image]